# Validator.pattern(RegEx) not working as I thought it would work

Tags: angular

This is a weird issue and I seem to find nothing about it anywhere. All the regex expressions I find everywhere are like this:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})
```

Bue when I pass that on my formControl like this:

```
'password': new FormControl( this.register.password, [ Validator.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})') ]
```

it doesnt validate when when I fullfill all the requirements of the password. Anyone out there that can give me a hand with this? I am new to regex expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validator isn't working because of the way the `pattern(string)` is implemented.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5eb7f3491f37a8f71717525b0d0e901c00a8c4e8/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L364) is the source code for the validator and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5eb7f3491f37a8f71717525b0d0e901c00a8c4e8/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L506) is the source code of its internals. The most intesting part for You is the line `if (typeof pattern === 'string')` which Your code is going through (as You passed a `string`, not `RegExp`).

I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pft9ko?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for You (to be honest, You should have created it).

Note how Your regex looks in the 1st example.

Now as You see the difference, it comes down to explain what the RegExp You put in is actualy doing and why it won't mach never ever.

This entire regexp is one giant [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which in basic terms means it is not going to march through entire input string, so it will never reach the `$` sign (bacause after matching it will forget about this lookahead and go back to 1st non-lookahead character, which is the start of the string), which means the `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})$` will never match.

- `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})$` - will never match (because it is just looking ahead from the beginning of the string, not ever going to satisfy `$`),
- `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})` - will match as we are naturaly starting from the beginning of the string.
- `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})` - will match any string that have at least 1 small letter, big letter, digit and special character, and it has to be of length more that 7.

Example: [link](https://regex101.com/r/9QiAUb/1)

So to summarize:

- do not copy something You do not understand and expect it to work,
- `Validators.pattern(string)` will add `^` and `$` signs at the beginning and the end of the string before converting it to a `RegExp`
- to not allow this, just use a `Validators.pattern(RegExp)`
- ... or just not do it lazy way by using the RegExp which for just a basic 8 character long string will do over `130` steps to validate it.

Comment: Thank you Eatos, and you are right, I should have made a StackBlitz for you guys to understand me better. Thank you for the time in your answer, I understand now that I should take my time to understand it better before implementing it.

Comment: And to be honest I would advice You to create Your own validator or look for some in npm. The pattern validator will give a user no clue why the password he inputted is incorrect. And having a couple of includes it fairly easy to write. I'll remove my downvote anyway (You have to edit the question in any way to enable me to upvote it)